# Jump to enclosing bracket in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Emacs C/C++/Perl/Lisp etc mode I can do <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to run `backward-up-list` which takes me to the open bracket containing the current cursor position.  For example, if I'm in a parameter list it takes me to the opening parenthesis after the function name, and if I'm in a statement it takes me to the opening brace for the block.  How do I do the same thing in Visual Studio Code (I'm running the Mac version).

I know about <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> running `Go to Bracket` but that takes you to the open/close bracket matching the close/open bracket under the cursor, which is more like <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> `backward-sexp` and <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> `forward-sexp`.

Comment: If you're willing to use plugins, there is VsCodeVim.

Comment: Hmmm... not sure I want to go back to command/insert mode switching just so I can use `[{` and `]}`, but thanks for the suggestion.  I think!

Comment: Have you tried any of the emacs extensions?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this VS Code extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OnlyLys.leaper

It provides the ability to leap out of autoclosing pairs with Tab.